# division by zero error while calculating growth percentage from two different tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The table I currently have looks like this: (data comes from two different tables, 19921231, 19930331)
[image]

The table I want to create looks like this (5th column added)
[image]

Goal: determine the deposit growth rate at each bank. I.e. Comparing the amount of deposits held at a bank in the previous quarter (e.g. 19921231) to the deposits of the most recent quarter (e.g. 19930331). Then view the increase/decrease as a percentage.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
select 
AL.repdte as `Date`, AL.cert, AL.name, AL.dep as `Deposits`
FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL

UNION ALL

select 
AL.repdte as `Date`, AL.cert, AL.name, AL.dep as `Deposits`
FROM usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as AL
```

An answer to this question suggested this code, that works However, for some reason I getting an output of "NULL"

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name and
        al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 year);
```

[image]

In an attempt to isolate the "NULL" issue, I was able to eliminate the "NULL" issue. I did so by  simplyfing the query. It worked I was able to view both quarters of "deposits".

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name
```

[image]

Once I determined that there didn't seem to be any problem with retrieving the deposit data from the last two quarters, I decided to remove  the last line of this code:

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name and
        al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 year);
```

To this:

```
select al19930331.repdte as `Date`, al19930331.cert, al19930331.name,
       al19930331.dep as Deposits_1993,
       al19921231.dep as Deposits_1992,
       (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / al19921231.dep as grow_rate
from usa_fdic_call_reports_1993.All_Reports_19930331_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19930331 left join
     usa_fdic_call_reports_1992.All_Reports_19921231_Assets_and_Liabilities as al19921231
     on al19930331.cert = al19921231.cert and
        al19930331.name = al19921231.name
```

This worked, sort of, however it exposed a "division by zero" error.   So now the question is how can add back a solution to eliminate the division by error, that would enable me to add the last line of code back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the divide-by-zero error, you can do a safe divide.  BigQuery has a function for this:

```
   IEEE_DIVIDE((al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep), al19921231.dep) as grow_rate
```

However, I am inclined to use `NULLIF()`, which is a standard SQL function:

```
   (al19930331.dep - al19921231.dep) / NULLIF(al19921231.dep, 0) as grow_rate
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you Gordon. 

FYI: I wasn't able to get a valid query while using the last line:
 al19921231.repdte = date_add(al19930331.repdte, interval 1 year); It returned Null on two of the three columns.